# Jersey + Spring loading a static html file with CORS

Tags: java, spring, web.xml, jersey-2.0

I am using jersey server 1.19 and have this web.xml configuration:

```
 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.rest.jersey.serviceConfigurer</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest-api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I am trying to load an .html file which is under my webapp/web folder.
The file is loaded, however I can not seem to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to *

When I change the url-pattern to /* It does set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to * but then the response from the server is a 404 error on the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found the solution I had to create my own StaticContentFilter.

My static resources are under webapp/web.

```
public class StaticContentFilter extends ServletContainer {


  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
          throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)response;
    res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT,OPTIONS");
    res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");

    chain.doFilter(request,response);
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {

  }
}
```

And also add this filter in the web.xml file

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>StaticContentFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.aaa.bbb.filters.StaticContentFilter</filter-class>


</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>StaticContentFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```